# Length of array of type String

Tags: c++, string

I have :

```
string a[] = {"akdhska","asjd","askjdh"};
```

Is there any way to get the number of elements in this array?

As a resolution of this I am doing the following:

```
vector<string> a;
a.insert(a.end(),"test1"); // or a.push_back("test1")
a.insert(a.end(),"test");
a.insert(a.end(),"test12");
a.insert(a.end(),"test123");
int len = a.size();
```

Comment: You can use `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)` as long you're in the same scope `a` was defined.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Scope doesn't matter!

Comment: If you have a somewhat modern compiler, you can also do `std::vector<std::string> a = {"akdhska","asjd","askjdh"};`

Comment: how does sizeof work for the String type? By default do we have a fixed siz for each string?

Comment: It isn't the string type that matters here, it is the length of the array.

Comment: @juanchopanza right!! so  we are dividing the total length of the array with the length of each block. so we have each block assigned a fixed size.

Answer (score 6):

A C++11 solution would be

```
std::size_t length = std::end(a) - std::begin(a);
```

or

```
std::size_t length = std::distance(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use :

```
int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
```

Comment: best for compile-time known tables, 0 CPU use (at place when is born) BUT NOT when table is passed as argument

Comment: @JacekCz It depends how it is passed. I.e. what the type of the parameter of the function is.

Answer (score 1):

```
string a[] = {"akdhska", "asjd", "askjdh"};
int len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a); // gives you number of elements
```

Comment: best for compile-time known tables, 0 CPU use (at place when is born) BUT NOT when table is passed as argument